# Laravel pagination how to paginate database results

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-9, laravel-pagination

I want to paginate my array, here is one function in one of my controllers.

```
public function index()
{
    $data = DB::select("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE articleCategory = 'Economie' AND articleDate = CURDATE() ORDER BY articleDate DESC, articleHour DESC, articleMinute ASC, articleSeconde ASC");
    return view('business', compact('data'));
}
```

I tried to do this :

```
$data = DB::select("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE articleCategory = 'Economie' AND articleDate = CURDATE() ORDER BY articleDate DESC, articleHour DESC, articleMinute ASC, articleSeconde ASC")->paginate(10);
```

But Laravel didn't recognize paginate()
--> Call to a member function paginate() on array

Answer (score 0):

```php
$data = DB::table('articles')
    ->where('articleCategory', 'Economie')
    ->whereRaw('`articleDate` = CURDATE()')
    //alternatively ->where('articleDate', now()) 
    ->orderBy('articleDate', 'desc')
    ->orderBy('articleHour', 'desc')
    ->orderBy('articleMinute', 'asc')
    ->orderBy('articleSeconde', 'asc')
    ->paginate();
```

Comment: What's the difference betwwen DB::table ... and what I've used ?

Comment: DB::select() makes the query right away

Comment: Can you add some more details please ?

Comment: Sorry. The select method on DB facade executes a query to the database and returns an array of results. in order to use laravel pagination you need to use the query builder https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/2a1a55caf3c65a74f173f47be594587cb931f22c/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php#L402

Comment: DB::table() returns a query builder instance https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/2a1a55caf3c65a74f173f47be594587cb931f22c/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php#L323

Comment: Hi again Raw ! I used your solution and it's working. But I'm facing a problem, I'm using head() function to get the first element of my array. But once I've used the query builder instead of the normal select, I guess the collection changed a bit since laravel didn't succeed to read some property from my array, as an exemple : Property [articleHref] does not exist on this collection instance.
This is the code i'm using @php $firstElementInter = head($dataInter);@endphp
any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I used this way.

```
 $data=Data::paginate(12);


$data=Data::orderBy('id', 'Asc')->paginate(12);
```

Data is Model name and 12 is number is number of paginate